# Record Count Different in VBA Versus Access

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ms-access

I have an Excel VBA workbook that generates a SQL statement in the form of a string. I pass this SQL into a recordset object and use the CopyFromRecordSet function to dump out the data into an Excel worksheet.

The above method gives me 67 records. If I take the exact SQL generated in VBA and paste into a new query within Access it provides 400 records.

SQL is the following:

```
SELECT  tbJob.jobID, 
        tbTasks.tskName, 
        tbTaskCat.catName, 
        tbTasks.tskActivity, 
        tbJob.JobDueDate, 
        tbJob.jobCompletedDate, 
        tbJob.jobCreatedOn, 
        tbJobStatus.statusDes, 
        tbStaff.staffForename & ' ' & tbStaff.staffSurname AS Assignee 
FROM    tbJobStatus 
        INNER JOIN (tbStaff 
            INNER JOIN (tbTaskCat 
                INNER JOIN (tbTasks 
                    INNER JOIN tbJob 
                    ON tbTasks.tskID = tbJob.jobTaskID) 
                ON tbTaskCat.catID = tbTasks.tskCatID) 
            ON tbStaff.staffID = tbJob.jobAssignedToID) 
        ON tbJobStatus.statusID = tbJob.jobStatusID 
WHERE   tbJob.jobStatusID = 4 
AND     tbJobStatus.statusDes <> 'Deleted' 
ORDER BY tbJob.jobID;
```

I am struggling to explain why the difference occurs.
Any help would be appreciated. I have searched around the web but couldn't find a solution, if you know of one please post the link.

Thanks in advance.

Stuart

Comment: What's the copyfromrecordset line of vba? to a single cell?

Comment: I would have to assume this is a difference in the interpretation of the criteria. Short of having your data to actually look at I think we'll be clutching at straws to be honest. Re-run with just one criteria statement in both access and excel and see if the differences are maintained / worse or better.

Comment: What happens if you directly connect to the query from Excel?

Comment: Hi Guys, Thank you for replying. The CopyFromRecordset is the following code: Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset objRS. Not sure what you mean by directly connecting to the query from Excel. Usually I always connect to MS Access via VBA.

Comment: @Minty. Thank you for the suggestion, I took your advice and tried a new very basic query. I got the same results as before so I am guessing there is an issue somewhere in my code that is causing this issue.

Comment: Have you compared the 67 to the 400? Are you getting just the first 67 of the 400, or is there something in the data that could explain the 67 as a sub-set of the 400?

Comment: Just to be safe, are you sure you are connecting to the same Access database from Excel as when you try the query directly?

Comment: Do you get the same results if you use `"` quotes to delimit strings instead of `'` quotes? Do you get different results if you use a DAO Recordset instead of an ADO Recordset? And is there a setting that is forcing binary compare on `tbJobStatus.statusDes <> 'Deleted' `

Comment: @Andre, you are spot on, I forgot I was connected to a test database versus prod...apologies guys.

Comment: Ah - ye Olde wrong database issue. Glad you sorted it.